# Restrict WooCommerce admin orders for specific user roles to specific order statusses

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, user-roles

is there a way to show certain order statuses for specific roles? E.g. Admin can see On-Hold, Processing, Completed, Trash, etc.  But Shop Manager can only see On-Hold, Processing, and Completed.

See screenshot:
[image]

So far I've tried this code that I found on this thread [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/order-status-visibility-by-role/) but it still showing all statuses for shop managers:

```
// Admin orders list: bulk order status change dropdown
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'filter_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order', 20, 1 );
function filter_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order( $actions ) {
    $new_actions = [];
    foreach( $actions as $key => $option ){
        // Targeting "shop_manager" | order statuses "on-hold" and "processing"
        if( current_user_can('shop_manager') && in_array( $key, array('mark_on-hold', 'mark_processing') ) ){
            $new_actions[$key] = $option;
        }
    }
    if( sizeof($new_actions) > 0 ) {
        return $new_actions;
    }
    return $actions;
}

// Admin order pages: Order status change dropdown
add_filter('wc_order_statuses', 'filter_order_statuses');
function filter_order_statuses($order_statuses) {
    global $pagenow;

    if( $pagenow === 'post.php' || $pagenow === 'post-new.php' ) {
        $new_order_statuses = array();

        foreach ($order_statuses as $key => $option ) {
            // Targeting "shop_manager" | order statuses "on-hold" and "processing"
            if( current_user_can('shop_manager') && in_array( $key, array('wc-on-hold', 'wc-processing') ) ){
                $new_order_statuses[$key] = $option;
            }
        }
        if( sizeof($new_order_statuses) > 0 ) {
            return $new_order_statuses;
        }
    }
    return $order_statuses;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have revisited your code in a better way and added the missing function that filter orders by allowed order statusses for specific user roles in admin orders list:

```
// Custom conditional fuction to target specific user roles
function user_roles_allowed_orders() {
    $targeted_roles = array('shop_manager'); // Here define your targeted user roles
    return (bool) array_intersect( wp_get_current_user()->roles, $targeted_roles );
}

// Admin orders list: bulk order status change dropdown
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'filter_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order', 100 );
function filter_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order( $actions ) {
    if ( user_roles_allowed_orders() ) {
        $allowed_actions = array('mark_on-hold', 'mark_processing');

        foreach( $actions as $key => $option ){
            if( ! in_array( $key, $allowed_actions ) ){
                unset($actions[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $actions;
}

// Admin order pages: Order status change dropdown
add_filter('wc_order_statuses', 'filter_order_statuses', 100 );
function filter_order_statuses( $statuses ) {
    global $pagenow, $typenow;

    if( in_array( $pagenow, array('post.php', 'post-new.php') )
    && 'shop_order' === $typenow && user_roles_allowed_orders() ) {
        $allowed_statusses = array('wc-on-hold', 'wc-processing');

        foreach ($statuses as $key => $option ) {
            if( ! in_array( $key, $allowed_statusses ) ){
                unset($statuses[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $statuses;
}

// Filter admin orders for shop managers based
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_shop_manager_orders', 100 );
function filter_shop_manager_orders( $query ) {
    global $pagenow, $post_type;
    //'shop_manager'
    if( $query->is_admin && 'edit.php' === $pagenow && 'shop_order' === $post_type
    && user_roles_allowed_orders() ){
        $allowed_statusses = array('wc-on-hold', 'wc-processing');

        $query->set( 'post_status', $allowed_statusses );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Hi Loic, thanks a lot. It works. Now, I'm wondering how do I hide those order status labels only for selected roles? E.g. If shop manager goes to woocommerce order backend page, they will only see on-hold and processing label instead of all listed labels in screenshot above (mine, quote, invoice, pending, etc.)

can this be done using CSS?

edited: add more comments.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to use "current_user_can"?  try in_array('user_role") to specify as single user role.